# Is intersection of a dense subspace and a closed subspace dense in the subspace?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and a closed operator $T$ defined on its domain $D(T)$ which is dense in H. Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $H$.

In 
[Is intersection of a dense subspace and a closed subspace of a Hilbert space also Dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545705/is-intersection-of-a-dense-subspace-and-a-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-als)
it is answered "$D(T)\cap M$ can never be dense in $H$" (the statement isn't really precise, can we let$M=H$ and still holds?).

But is $D(T)\cap M$ dense in $M$?

Let $f\in M\subset H$, then there is $g\in D(T)$ such that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have
$
\|f-g\|_H<\epsilon.
$
But I am not sure if I can take $g$ from $D(T)\cap M$.

If not in general, when? (except for the trivial case $M\subset D(T)$) .

Comment: What if $v$ is in $H\setminus D(T)$ and $M=\mathbb C v$?  I don't know about "when"?  Edit: I clicked your link and see Martin's answer would also provide you a counterexample, a specific case of what I mentioned.

Comment: In light of the comment by @JonasMeyer (you beat me by $2$ seconds), you may want to add the hypothesis $D(T)\cap M$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @Aweygan: But then what if $v$ is as above and $0\neq w\in D(T)$, and $M=\mathrm{span}\{v,w\}$?

Comment: BTW, any  subspace of a separable HIlbert space has a countable dense subset from general principles  (this holds in all metric spaces, where separable is equivalent to having a countable open base). These examples just show that we cannot expect the same dense subset to work everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fail as the fine example by [Martin Agerami](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1546849/4280) shows. There we have a dense subset $N$ of $H$ and a closed subspace $M$ such that $N \cap M = \{0\}$, so certainly not dense in $M$.

We can say it is dense though when we know that the interior of $M$ is non-empty, but in a normed space this implies that $M = H$ already. In topological terms, you cannot say more, $H \setminus D$, where $D$ is a dense subspace of $H$, might contain closed subspaces (like the span of finitely many vectors not in $D$) that $D$ is not dense in. We can only say $D$ restricted to open subsets is dense in that open subset, but as said, an open *subspace* is automatically the whole space, so that buys you very little.