# A $\ast$-representation of a $C^{*}$-algebra on a Hilbert space $H$ that is non-degenerate on a dense subspace $D\subset H$.

Tags: operator-theory, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Suppose that $\pi$ is a $\ast$-representation of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$ on some Hilbert space $H$. We say that $\pi$ is *non-degenerate* if for each $0\neq y\in H$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $\pi(a)y\neq0$.

Now suppose that $D\subset H$ is a dense subspace and that for each $0\neq x\in D$ there is an $a\in A$ such that $\pi(a)x\neq0$. (I guess one could say that $\pi$ is non-degenerate on $D$.)

Can we conclude from this that $\pi$ is non-degenerate?

**My attempt:** Since I couldn't find any counterexamples, I tried to find a proof instead. Let $0\neq y\in H$ be given. Fix some sufficiently small $\varepsilon>0$, which can later be chosen suitably. By density, there exists some $x\in D$ such that $\|x-y\|<\varepsilon$. Since we may assume that $\varepsilon<\|y\|/2$, it follows that $x\neq0$. Hence by assumption there is an $a\in A$ such that $\pi(a)x\neq0$. Now I was hoping that $\pi(a)y\neq0$, but since our choice of $\varepsilon$ may *not* depend on $a$ and $x$, I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: I am not sure if your definition makes sense, $\pi$ is a representation onto an Hilbert space so $\pi(a)$ is a operator on $H$. Your second statement does not make sense now. Should it be for each $d\in D$ there exists a $x\in H$ such that $\pi(d)x\neq 0$?

Comment: @sein Thanks. Apparently, I made a mistake when I copied it from my hand-written notes. I edited the post, including the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice question. It misguided my intuition at first. The answer turns out to be negative. While trying to prove that the answer was positive, I noted that the main obstruction was that a dense subspace of a Hilbert space must not intersect all closed subspaces. Starting from there, it is not too hard to construct a counterexample.

Choose a Hilbert space $H$ with a dense subspace $D$ and a closed proper subspace $0 \ne M$ such that $M\cap D = 0$ (see [Is intersection of a dense subspace and a closed subspace of a Hilbert space also Dense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545705/is-intersection-of-a-dense-subspace-and-a-closed-subspace-of-a-hilbert-space-als/1546849#1546849)).

Then the canonical faithful representation $\pi: B(M^\perp) \hookrightarrow B(H): x \mapsto 0 \oplus x$
where
$$(0 \oplus x)(m+m^\perp) = xm^\perp \in M^\perp$$
is degenerate (it is non-unital). However, given $0 \ne d \in D\subseteq M \oplus M^\perp$, write $d = m + m^\perp$. Note that $m^\perp \ne 0$, since $M \cap D=0$. But then we can choose $x \in B(M^\perp)$ with $x m^\perp \ne 0$ and then
$$\pi(x)d = x m^\perp \ne 0.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you mean $D\subset M\oplus M^{\perp}$ instead of equality?

Comment: @Calculix Yes, that's a typo. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Clever counterexample! I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Calculix You are very welcome!